# Retrieving data from Firebase with same id repeated multiple time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this firebase structure:

[image: firebase structure]

I am trying to retrieve data under the key `FA16-BCS-B16-B-MONDAY`. What I am getting is:

[image]

where line 4,5,6 doesn't include in the `FA16-BCS-B16-B-MONDAY`, but in other category.

the code i have tried till now is:

```
final DatabaseReference childRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("TimeTable");//.child("FA16-BCS-B16-B-MONDAY");
    //adding listener
 childRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         Iterable<DataSnapshot> snapshotIterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
         Iterator<DataSnapshot> iterator = snapshotIterator.iterator();
         adapter.clear();
         teacher.clear();
         while (iterator.hasNext() ) {
             DataSnapshot next =  iterator.next();

             String course=  next.child("course").getValue().toString();
             String teacher= next.child("teacher").getValue().toString();
             String time= next.child("time").getValue().toString();

             String key = next.getKey();
             //teacher.add(key);
             adapter.add(course+"\t"+teacher+"\t"+time);}
         listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I don't know why the data of other children is being retrieved. If I use

```
    final DatabaseReference childRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("TimeTable").child("FA16-BCS-B16-B-MONDAY");
```

it retrieves only one result. Please help me figure this out. Thanks

Comment: All the children beneath `TimeTable` node have the same structure? Can you please expand one more child? So you need to get all the data beneath those objects, right?

Comment: they have the same child but different data, @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve only a single child node from the time table, you need to remove the loop from your `onDataChange`. So something like:

```
final DatabaseReference childRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
  .child("TimeTable").child("FA16-BCS-B16-B-MONDAY");
//adding listener
childRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    adapter.clear();
    teacher.clear();
    String course = dataSnapshot.child("course").getValue().toString();
    String teacher = dataSnapshot.child("teacher").getValue().toString();
    String time= dataSnapshot.child("time").getValue().toString();

    String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();

    System.out.println(key+": "+course+", "+teacher+", "+time);

    adapter.add(course+"\t"+teacher+"\t"+time);}

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
```

---

**Update**

To read all timetables, you can listen one level higher in the tree and then loop over the child nodes you get back:

```
final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("TimeTable");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    adapter.clear();
    teacher.clear();
    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      String course = childSnapshot.child("course").getValue().toString();
      String teacher = childSnapshot.child("teacher").getValue().toString();
      String time= childSnapshot.child("time").getValue().toString();

      String key = childSnapshot.getKey();

      System.out.println(key+": "+course+", "+teacher+", "+time);

      adapter.add(course+"\t"+teacher+"\t"+time);}
    });

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
```

Comment: i want to retrieve multiple childs